# facebook-api story album ads

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api-v2.3

In order to make advertise story album posts using post engagement ads via API, we made an album (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/album), added photos to that album (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/album/photos), and then uploaded ads using page_story_id of photos.

However, we are not seeing story containing many photos like “added 3 new photos to the album: album_name.” Instead, we can only upload ads showing one photo like "added a new photo to the album: album_name."

Is there a way we can make story album displaying multiple images through API?

Thank you in advance.

--

```
// create album
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.3/{page_id}/albums
{
    "name":"album_name"
}

// add photos in album
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.3/{album_id}
{
    "message":"album_name"
    ,"place" : page_id
    ,"no_story" : "false"
    ,"url" : "some img url"
} // 3 times (get object_story_id)

// create campaign_group
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.3/{act_adaccountid}/adcampaign_groups
{
    "name":"POST_ENGAGEMENT"
    ,"campaign_group_status" : "ACTIVE"
    ,"objective" : "POST_ENGAGEMENT"
}

// create adcampaign
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.3/{act_adaccountid}/adcampaigns
{
    "start_time":"POST_ENGAGEMENT"
    ,"campaign_status" : "ACTIVE"
    ,"name" : "POST_ENGAGEMENT"
    ,"end_time" : "1430485200"
    ,"lifetime_budget" : 35000
    ,"targeting" : "{"age_max":30,"age_min":20,"geo_locations":{"countries":["KR"]},"page_types":["feed"]}"
    ,"bid_type" : "CPC"
    ,"bid_info" : "{CLICKS: 10}"
    ,"campaign_group_id" : campaign_group_id
}

// create adgroup
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.3/{act_adaccountid}/adgroups
{
    "name":"POST_ENGAGEMENT"
    ,"campaign_id" : campaign_id
    ,"creative" : {"object_story_id":object_story_id}
    ,"conversion_specs":{"action.type":["DEFAULTS"]}
}
```

Comment: Perhaps your question will become clearer if you also post some code samples to better describe how you are using the API.

Comment: I just add api code. thank you

Comment: Are you sure you're using the ID of the story, or the ID of the album itself?

Comment: it can't make ad using ID of the album. only using photo's object_story_id. FB is not support using album's ID of the story